# Attaching relevent excel file to auto-email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written code to export my data by manufacturer name into new books named for the manufacturer.

Now I have tweaked an email macro to automatically email the manufacturers.

I'd like it to automatically attach my files from My Documents

Here's what I have, but it attaches nothing.

```
Sub BacklogEmail()
Dim subjectLine As String
Dim bodyline As String
Dim tb As ListObject
Dim lineCounter As Long
Dim myArray1, arrayCounter As Long, tempNumb As Long
Dim nameCounter As Long
Dim emAddress As String
ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)
arrayCounter = 0
nameCounter = 1

Set tb = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10")


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10").ListRows.Count
    emAddress = tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, tb.ListColumns("Email Address").Index)
    For X = LBound(myArray1) To UBound(myArray1)
        On Error Resume Next
        If emAddress = myArray1(X) Then GoTo goToNext
    Next X
        On Error GoTo 0
        subjectLine = "Obsolescence Report for Manufacturer(s)  "
        ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To nameCounter)
        myArray1(nameCounter) = emAddress
        nameCounter = nameCounter + 1
        lineCounter = 1
            With tb.ListColumns("Email Address").Range
                Set C = .Find(emAddress, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not C Is Nothing Then
                    firstaddress = C.Address
                    Beep
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Do
                        Nrow = C.Row - 1
                        If lineCounter = 1 Then
                            subjectLine = subjectLine & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index)
                            lineCounter = lineCounter + 1
                           ' bodyline = "Manufacturer " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index) & ",  Manufacturer Item Number " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Item Number").Index)
                        Else:
                            subjectLine = subjectLine
                            'bodyline = bodyline & vbNewLine & "Manufacturer " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index) & ",  Manufacturer Item Number " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Item Number").Index)
                        End If

                        Set C = .FindNext(C)
                    Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstaddress
                End If
                        Run SendMailFunction(emAddress, subjectLine, bodyline)
'                        Debug.Print vbNewLine
'                        Debug.Print emAddress
'                        Debug.Print "Subject: " & subjectLine
'                        Debug.Print "Body:" & vbNewLine; bodyline
            End With
goToNext:
Next i
Set C = Nothing
End Sub




Function SendMailFunction(emAddress As String, subjectLine As String, bodyline As String)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim tb As ListObject
Dim NL As String
Dim DNL As String
Dim lineCounter As Long
Dim myArray1, arrayCounter As Long, tempNumb As Long
Dim nameCounter As Long
ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)
arrayCounter = 0
nameCounter = 1

NL = vbNewLine
DNL = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set tb = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10")

           ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To nameCounter)
           myArray1(nameCounter) = emAddress
           nameCounter = nameCounter + 1
           lineCounter = 1
            With tb.ListColumns("Email Address").Range
                Set C = .Find(emAddress, LookIn:=xlValues)
               If Not C Is Nothing Then
                    firstaddress = C.Address
                    Beep
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                        Nrow = C.Row - 1
                      If lineCounter = 1 Then
                      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
       On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail

            .To = emAddress
            .Subject = subjectLine
            .Body = "Hello, attached is an excel file that we require you to complete. " & _
                    "This is required by as we must know when parts are going to become obsolete. " & _
                    "We appriciate your contribution to keeping our databases current. " & _
                    "Thank you for your timely response."
                            .Attachments.Add "U:\\\\" & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index) & ".xlsx"
                            lineCounter = lineCounter + 1

           .Display


     On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing


End With
End If
End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: What are you doing with `Format(Now(), "********")`? That resolves to nothing at all?

Comment: Your program is trying to attach a file called `C:\Users\dmack\my Documents\Manufacturer Name.xlsx` to each mail. Presumably that doesn't exist so is unable to attach it.

Comment: ...and you're not getting errors because you've used `On Error Resume Next` to disable them.

Comment: sorry I uploaded the wrong set of code, I was trying to integrate another set of code.

Comment: You still have On Error Resume Next after Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0). Remove it so you can see errors and fix them yourself.

Comment: I comment them out when running through. See edited code.

Comment: Can you share/post example of spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the answer fully working and able to loop through the list of emails and send the required excel files. It will send 200 emails in under 5 minutes. Correctly. Cheers to all that helped!

```
Sub BacklogEmail()
Dim subjectLine As String
Dim bodyline As String
Dim tb As ListObject
Dim lineCounter As Long
Dim myArray1, arrayCounter As Long, tempNumb As Long
Dim nameCounter As Long
Dim emAddress As String
ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)
arrayCounter = 0
nameCounter = 1

Set tb = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10")


For I = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10").ListRows.Count
    emAddress = tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(I, tb.ListColumns("Email Address").Index)
    For X = LBound(myArray1) To UBound(myArray1)
        On Error Resume Next
        If emAddress = myArray1(X) Then GoTo goToNext
    Next X
        On Error GoTo 0
        subjectLine = "Update Required For on Order(s) # "
        ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To nameCounter)
        myArray1(nameCounter) = emAddress
        nameCounter = nameCounter + 1
        lineCounter = 1
            With tb.ListColumns("Email Address").Range
                Set C = .Find(emAddress, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not C Is Nothing Then
                    firstaddress = C.Address
                    Beep
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    Do
                        Nrow = C.Row - 1
                        If lineCounter = 1 Then
                            subjectLine = subjectLine & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index)
                            lineCounter = lineCounter + 1
                            bodyline = "Order " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index) & ",  Manufacturer Item Number " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Item Number").Index)
                        Else:
                            subjectLine = subjectLine
                            bodyline = bodyline & vbNewLine & "Order " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index) & ",  Manufacturer Item Number " & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Item Number").Index)
                        End If

                        Set C = .FindNext(C)
                        Debug.Print vbNewLine
                        Debug.Print emAddress
                        Debug.Print "Subject: " & subjectLine
                        Debug.Print "Body:" & vbNewLine; bodyline
                    Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstaddress
                End If

                        Run SendMailFunction(emAddress, subjectLine, bodyline)


            End With
goToNext:
Next I
Set C = Nothing
End Sub


Function SendMailFunction(emAddress As String, subjectLine As String, bodyline As String)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim tb As ListObject
Dim NL As String
Dim DNL As String
Dim lineCounter As Long
Dim myArray1, arrayCounter As Long, tempNumb As Long
Dim nameCounter As Long
ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)
arrayCounter = 0
nameCounter = 1

NL = vbNewLine
DNL = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set tb = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10")

           ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To nameCounter)
          myArray1(nameCounter) = emAddress
           nameCounter = nameCounter + 1
           lineCounter = 1
            With tb.ListColumns("Email Address").Range
                Set C = .Find(emAddress, LookIn:=xlValues)
               If Not C Is Nothing Then
                    firstaddress = C.Address
                    Beep
                    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                        Nrow = C.Row - 1
                      If lineCounter = 1 Then

      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
       On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail

            .To = emAddress
            .Subject = subjectLine
            .Body = "Hello, attached is an excel file that we require you to complete. " & _
                    "This is required by as we must know when parts are going to become obsolete. " & DNL & _
                    "We appriciate your contribution to keeping our databases current. " & DNL & _
                    "Thank you for your timely response."
            .Attachments.Add ":\\\\\" & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb.ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index) & ".xlsx"
                            lineCounter = lineCounter + 1

           .Display

      End With
     On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing


End If
End If
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `attach.add` line to:

```
Debug.Print "C:\users\dmack\my documents\" & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb, ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index)
```

and if you start seeing the correct **full** filepath\filenames in the Immediate Window, then change it again, to:

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\users\dmack\my documents\" & tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(Nrow, tb, ListColumns("Manufacturer Name").Index)
```

Comment: So I have it automatically pointing at the correct file, but it wont attach the file. When I change debug.print to attachments.add it also will no longer open the email. See above for edited code

Comment: When you use debug.print, what gets written to the Immediate window? Is it a valid path/filename?

Comment: Yes it is, I have updated the code. It now attaches. But has broken my loop for sending multiple emails. It only generates one now, can you see where ive gone wrong on the return to the first section?

Comment: In these cases, I tend to just 'step' through the code using F8 within the VBE to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: It goes through the first time, populates the email, attaches the file and then returns back to the top. When it runs the second time it enters the loop in the top section and that's where it breaks, it never leaves just constantly runs through the upper loop.

Comment: The `For X...` loop, or the `For i...` loop?

Comment: It was the For X - but I fixed it, and now the program works when ran. But does not work when gone through line by line with F8. Which is weird. Don't suppose you have any ideas on that one?

Comment: Not much. If it works fine when left alone but `F8` causes issues then that's *normally* where the focus is reverting back to the VB Editor, but the code is relying on Active sheet or similar to work properly, such as when cells are Selected etc.. Your code could probably do with refactoring to remove any instances of this kind. The only one I can see is `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table10")` which should probably be `Sheets("theSheetName").ListObjects("Table10")` that you `Set` to `TB`. Also, your `For I = 1 To...` loop should probably then read: `For I = 1 To TB.ListRows.Count`.